# How can I let the width of a control be the width of the current device?

Tags: ios, swift

For example, I create a `UITableView` in the storyboard and I want to get a `UITableViewCell` with a fixed proportion (e.g. **16:1**).

1. Example: If on **5s**, I want the `UITableViewCell` with the frame `(width:320, height:20)`.
2. Example: If on **6plus**, I want the `UITableViewCell` with the frame `(width:640, height:40)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `UITableViewCell` it's fairly easy, just implement this method in you `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.frame.size.width / 16.0
}
```

And in order to place your subviews accordingly, you'd need to add constraints to them. With anything else than a `UITableViewCell` it could get a little tricky, but again - AutoLayout and constraints are your friends.

Comment: OK,I thought I realize what you said.But there is more important issue when I set the constraints to the content view of TableViewCell.I can't add a new constraint for the content view or TableViewCell

Comment: Sure you can - you don't have to do it only in the storyboard, you can do it programmatically too.